# C++ errors, maybe coming from .h files, not sure

Tags: c++, header-files

Ok, I am trying to compile a program:

> g++ -std=c++0x a1test.cpp GS1Prefix.cpp EAN.cpp

But I am getting errors that I never seen before.

```
In file included from a1test.cpp:17:0:
EAN.h:3:25: error: âPrefixâ does not name a type
EAN.h:3:33: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âpâ with no type [-fpermissive]
a1test.cpp: In function âbool RegisteredTests(const Prefix*, int&, int*, int*)â:
a1test.cpp:222:68: error: no matching function for call to âisRegistered(const Prefix*&, const char [14], char [6], char [8], char [7])â
a1test.cpp:222:68: note: candidates are:
EAN.h:3:6: note: bool isRegistered(const int*, const char*, char*, char*, char*)
EAN.h:3:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âconst Prefix*â to âconst int*â
GS1Prefix.h:10:6: note: bool isRegistered(const Prefix*, int)
GS1Prefix.h:10:6: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 5 provided
```

This is just half of the errors, below i have all the .h files and a link to a1test.cpp (its a long code)

EAN.h

```
bool isValid(const char* str);
bool isRegistered(const Prefix* p, const char* str, char area[],char publisher[], char title[]);
```

GS1Prefix.h

```
const int MAX = 700;
struct Prefix {
    int  no;             // number of entries
    int  area[MAX];      // area elements
    char pubLow[MAX][8]; // low end of publisher range
    char pubHgh[MAX][8]; // high end of publisher range
    int  pubLen[MAX];    // no of chars in publisher string
};
bool load(const char* filename, Prefix* p);
bool isRegistered(const Prefix* p, int area);
int minNoDigits(const Prefix* p, int area);
bool isRegistered(const Prefix* p, int area, const char* publisher);
```

Link to a1test.cpp ->[a1test.cpp](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3bdc)

UPDATE: As suggested by remyabel, i made #include "GS1Prefix.h" after #include "EAN.h"

```
In file included from EAN.cpp:6:0:
EAN.h:3:25: error: âPrefixâ does not name a type
EAN.h:3:33: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âpâ with no type [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: `EAN.h` should come after `GS1Prefix.h`.

Comment: What was the last thing you changed before the errors appeared? I mean, you didn't write all of this code before testing any of it, did you?

Comment: no, i didn't. My prof did. there are 2 file to compile my program with. 
1.This tests my functions: g++ -std=c++0x a1test.cpp GS1Prefix.cpp EAN.cpp
2.The program:g++ -std=c++0x a1main.cpp GS1Prefix.cpp EAN.cpp

Comment: My program works fine with a1main.cpp, not with a1test.cpp

Comment: @hank99 did you try to use a typedef for your structure `Prefix`?

Comment: @rullof I just did, now i have even more errors.

Answer (score 2):

Simply switch the order of your headers and your code should compile fine. Because you did not provide `GS1Prefix.cpp` and `EAN.cpp` I cannot comment on the rest of the errors (if there are any left.)

```
#include <cstring>

// GS1Prefix.h
const int MAX = 700;
struct Prefix {
    int  no;             // number of entries
    int  area[MAX];      // area elements
    char pubLow[MAX][8]; // low end of publisher range
    char pubHgh[MAX][8]; // high end of publisher range
    int  pubLen[MAX];    // no of chars in publisher string
};
// EAN.h
bool isValid(const char* str);
bool isRegistered(const Prefix* p, const char* str, char area[],char publisher[], char title[]);
// a1test.cpp
bool load(const char* filename, Prefix* p);
bool isRegistered(const Prefix* p, int area);
int minNoDigits(const Prefix* p, int area);
bool isRegistered(const Prefix* p, int area, const char* publisher);
// .. rest of your file
```

Comment: Thanks! In my EAN.cpp I had #include "GS1Prefix.h" before #include "EAN.h", but i still have the first 3 errors.

Answer (score 1):

Header files should include sufficient definition so that they are self-sufficient.  In this case you need to supply a definition of the requisite type, Prefix.  Just add the include to the top of EAN.h:

```
#include <GS1Prefix.h>
bool isValid(const char* str);
bool isRegistered(const Prefix* p, const char* str, char area[],char publisher[],
                  char title[]);
```

Then you can include EAN.h in any source file knowing that you don't have dependencies to worry about.